# BindingResolutionException in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new for laravel and I start to use Laravel 5.2

I am making an admin panel so I created a Middleware calling Admin. However there is a binding error and I have no idea about how can I fix that.

My routes.php code is that:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function(){
    Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

This is my Admin.php:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;
use App\Models\AssignedRole;

class Admin
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $response;
    protected function __construct(Guard $auth,ResponseFactory $response)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->response = $response;
    }
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($this->auth->check())
        {
            $admin = 0;
            if($this->auth->user()->admin === '1')
            {
                $admin = 1;
            }
            if($admin === 0)
            {
                return $this->response->redirectTo('/');
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        return $this->response->redirectTo('/');
    }
}
```

This is my routeMiddleware in the Kernel.php file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = array(
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class
);
```

And exception message is: 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [App\Http\Middleware\Admin] is not instantiable.' in C:\wamp64\www\neredenal\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752

Any idea to fix this exception?

Comment: Do you have set up any Route model binding in RouteServiceProvider or AppServiceProvider?

Comment: No, I didn't something like that. Can you explain how can I create a service provider to fix my problem?